# I deleted etc/apache2 on my Mac OS Mojave

Tags: macos, bash, apache-http-server

While trying to set up my local host environment, I deleted my apache2 folder using the terminal command `rm -rf etc/apache2`.  How can I revert to default apache2 settings?  I am thinking of reinstalling my Mac OS in recovery mode – is that a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling the entire OS seems like overkill.  If you have another mac running mojave you can just copy the `/etc/apache2` directory over from it.  It looks like the only machine-specific settings are in `/etc/apache2/users` which have a file per username called `/etc/apache2/users/USERNAME.conf` and look like

```
<Directory "/Users/USERNAME/Sites/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Hello I do not have another Mac ? Do you have another Mac ?

Comment: @HenryTirla - you don't *need* another mac.  You can just download Mojave from App Store, install on a different partition or external disk then copy directory as marathon says.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your suggestions.What I Did is had a friend send over his etc/Apache2 folder since we running on the same OS and I just did the set up. Thank you for everything guys